# Including XML File in bin folder of ASP.NET Web Site Project

Tags: asp.net

I need to get an XML file from the bin folder of a class library included with my ASP.Net Web Site.  Right now, when I build the project, the xml file is in the bin folder of the class library but it does not get copied into the bin folder of the web site.

I've seen a solution of using the post-build event but those are only in web application projects so I can't use that?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an elegant/easy way to do this for your web site project (you can't even add the /bin folder to the project like you could with a web app project template).

What I'd suggest is that instead of putting the .xml into your /bin, I'd put it in a /config folder or other appropriate folder and reference from there.

Comment: I would suggest placing it within the "App_Data" folder.

Comment: This is the only solution I found too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change property of file (f4) to be copy to output directory = true

Should do as you wish.

Dan

Comment: Doesn't work with a web site project (does work for a web app project).

Answer (score 0):

Add the file as a resource to your project (project properties, "Resources", click "Add Resource" and select "Add existing file...".

Now you can access the content of the file like this:

```
Properties.Resources.YourResourceName;
```

You can "recreate" the file with a few lines of code. Global.asac.cs would be great place for this:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... get the bin directory ...
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(YourBinDir))
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(YourBinDir, Properties.Resources.YourResourceName);
    }
}
```

But I would also recommend that you store files like this in the App_Data folder. Whether you chose to deploy them with the rest of your app, or let the dll recreate them if they're missing, is really up to you. :)